# Suppress page numbers in article documentclass

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, titles

I want to suppress page numbers. I am also using `\maketitle` command which seems to trigger the problem. MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,english]{article}
\title{My title}
\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \maketitle
    Hello World
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You need to set the page style *after* `\maketitle` since `\maketitle` sets the page using `\thispagestyle{plain}` (which overwrites your request for it to be `empty`):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,english]{article}
\title{My title}
\begin{document}
 \maketitle
 \thispagestyle{empty}% Reset page style to 'empty'
 Hello World
\end{document}
```

If you wish to suppress the page numbering for all pages within your article, you should add `\pagestyle{empty}` to your document preamble.

The `article` document class also supports the `titlepage` option, which typesets an entire page (a `titlepage`) when using `\maketitle`. Such a page is necessarily issued using `\thispagestyle{empty}`. That is, without any header/footer.

Comment: @Elec: If you want to suppress _all_ page numbers (and other header and footer text) use `\pagestyle{empty}`.

Answer (score 43):

To suppress page numbers on every page regardless of the page style(s) used by the document class, add `\pagenumbering{gobble}` to your preamble.

Comment: `\gobble` and friends are nifty.

Answer (score 5):

`\pagenumbering{gobble}` will interact badly with `hyperref` if you have links going from the citations to the page numbers

On the other hand it can be a hassle to have to redefine the pagestyle after `\maketitle` in the document instead of having all your styles defined in the preamble.

To have the best of both words you can put in the preamble:

```
\pagestyle{empty}
\let\svmaketitle\maketitle
\def\maketitle{\svmaketitle\thispagestyle{empty}}
```

which will patch the `\maketitle` command to set the empty page style automatically.